# Migrating from AppState API to Saved Games API

Tags: android

So I'm trying to put some modifications on this code now the problem is the application refuses to connect to the game play service and load data , because it uses the old appstate api ! Now i need to migrate from the old Appstate to the new Saved Gamed API

The Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="maths.workout.jellyapp"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name="com.arkay.funwithmaths.HomeMenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.arkay.funwithmaths.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.arkay.funwithmaths.MultiPlayerPlayActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
     </activity>


     <activity
        android:name="com.arkay.funwithmaths.SinglePlayerPlayFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
     </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.arkay.funwithmaths.SettingActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
     </activity>

     <!-- <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" /> -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

      <!-- Google Play Service -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />



    <!-- End Google Play  -->
</application>
```

The Home Menu Activiy

```
package com.arkay.funwithmaths;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import maths.workout.jellyapp.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager;
import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;

/**
 * Home Screen of the app. It will display tow button one for Play and one for play multiplayer
 * @author I-BALL
 *
 */

public class HomeMenuActivity extends BaseGameActivity  implements
    View.OnClickListener,  GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, SinglePlayerPlayFragment.Listener  {

     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "preferences";
     private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

     public static final String MUSIC_SOUND = "music_sound";
     public static final String SOUND_EFFECT = "sound_effect";
     public static final String VIBRATION = "vibration";

     public static final String THIS_lEVEL_TOTAL_SCORE = "this_level_total_score";
     public static final String IS_LAST_LEVEL_COMPLETED = "is_last_level_completed";
     public static final String LAST_LEVEL_SCORE = "last_level_score";

     public static final String MULTI_PLAYER_TOP_TRUE_SCORE="multi_player_game_score";

     //Achivement
     public static final String HOW_MANY_TIMES_PLAY_QUIZ = "how_many_time_play_quiz";
     public static final String HOW_MANY_QUESTION_COMPLETED = "count_question_completed";
     public static final String LEVEL_COMPLETED = "level_completed";
     public static final String TOTAL_SCORE = "total_score";
     public static final String LEVEL ="level";

     public static final String VERY_CURIOUS_UNLOCK="is_very_curious_unlocked";

     private Button btnSinglePlayer, btnMultiplayer, btnSetting,btnAchivement,btnLeaderBoard,btnHelp;
     final int RC_RESOLVE = 5000, RC_UNUSED = 5001;
     private static final int OUR_STATE_KEY = 2;

     private GameData gameData;
     SharedPreferences settings;
     SinglePlayerPlayFragment singlePlayerFragment;

     /** The view to show the ad. */
      private AdView adView;
      //Intersial Ads
     private InterstitialAd interstitial;
     private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

     private ProgressDialog progress;

     public HomeMenuActivity() {
         super( BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_GAMES | BaseGameActivity.CLIENT_APPSTATE);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_menu);

        settings = getSharedPreferences(HomeMenuActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        gameData = new GameData(getSharedPreferences(HomeMenuActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0));

        btnSinglePlayer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSinglePlayer);
        btnSinglePlayer.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMultiplayer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMultiplayer);
        btnMultiplayer.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSetting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetting);
        btnSetting.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnAchivement = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAchivement);
        btnAchivement.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnLeaderBoard = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLeaderBoard);
        btnLeaderBoard.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnHelp= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnHelp);
        btnHelp.setOnClickListener(this);

        checkDB();

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        singlePlayerFragment = new SinglePlayerPlayFragment();
        singlePlayerFragment.setListener(this);

        SignInButton mSignInButton = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // start the asynchronous sign in flow
                System.out.println("Click on Sign-in");
                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
            }
        });

        /** Create the interstitial.*/
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_intersititial));

        /** Create ad request. */
        Resources ress = getResources();
        /**set testmost false when publish app*/
        boolean isTestMode = ress.getBoolean(R.bool.istestmode); 
        AdRequest adRequest =null;
        if(isTestMode){
              adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
             .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
             .addTestDevice("B15149A4EC1ED23173A27B04134DD483").build();
        }else{
             adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        }
        /** Begin loading your interstitial. */
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(getApplicationContext());
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_banner));

        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size until the ad is loaded.
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads_layout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateUITimerTask, 10 * 1200);

        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setTitle("Please Wait!!");
        progress.setMessage("Data Loading..");
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.show();

    }

    /**
     * Display Interstital ads.
     */
    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
      }

    public void checkDB() {
        try {
            String packageName = this.getPackageName();
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/databases";
            String fullPath = "/data/data/" + packageName + "/databases/"+ DATABASE_NAME;
            // this database folder location
            File f = new File(destPath);
            // this database file location
            File obj = new File(fullPath);
            // check if databases folder exists or not. if not create it
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdirs();
                f.createNewFile();
            }else{
                boolean isDelete = f.delete();
                Log.i("Delete", "Delete"+isDelete);

            }

            // check database file exists or not, if not copy database from assets
            if (!obj.exists()) {
                this.CopyDB(fullPath);
            }else{
                this.CopyDB(fullPath);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void CopyDB(String path) throws IOException {

        InputStream databaseInput = null;
        String outFileName = path;
        OutputStream databaseOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        // open database file from asset folder
        databaseInput = this.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        while ((length = databaseInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            databaseOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            databaseOutput.flush();
        }
        databaseInput.close();

        databaseOutput.flush();
        databaseOutput.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInFailed() {
        System.out.println("Sing In Fail");
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        System.out.println("Sing In Succcess");
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        loadFromCloud();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        System.out.println("Result Code: onConnectionFailed: " + arg0);
    }

    public void unlockAchievement(int achievementId, String fallbackString) {
        if (isSignedIn()) {
            Games.Achievements.unlock(getApiClient(), getString(achievementId));
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartGameRequested(boolean hardMode) {
         getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
         this.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowAchievementsRequested() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isSignedIn()) {
            startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()),
                    RC_UNUSED);
        } else {
            showAlert(getString(R.string.achievements_not_available));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowLeaderboardsRequested() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignInButtonClicked() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSignOutButtonClicked() {

    }
    boolean addList = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        this.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
            super.onBackPressed();
            displayInterstitial(false);
        }

    }
     public void displayInterstitial(boolean isFirstTime) {
            if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
              interstitial.show();
              if(isFirstTime){
                  // Create the interstitial.
                    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
                    interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_intersititial));

                    // Begin loading your interstitial.
                    interstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
              }
            }
          }



    @Override
    public void displyHomeScreen() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

     /**
     * Update leaderboards with the user's score.
     *
     * @param finalScore The score the user got.
     */
    @Override
    public void updateLeaderboards(int finalScore) {
        if (isSignedIn()) {
            if (finalScore >= 0) {
                Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard_fun_with_maths),
                       finalScore);

                byte[] scoreData = intToByteArray(finalScore); 
                AppStateManager.update(getApiClient(), 1, scoreData);


            }
        }
    }
    public static byte[] intToByteArray(int a) {
        return BigInteger.valueOf(a).toByteArray();
    }

    public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
        return new BigInteger(b).intValue();
    }


     public  void loadFromCloud() {
          if(isSignedIn()){
            AppStateManager.load(getGameHelper().getApiClient(), OUR_STATE_KEY).setResultCallback(mResultCallback);
          }
        }

     public   void saveToCloud() {
         if(isSignedIn()){
            AppStateManager.update(getGameHelper().getApiClient(), OUR_STATE_KEY, gameData.toBytes());
         }
        }


        ResultCallback<AppStateManager.StateResult> mResultCallback = new
                ResultCallback<AppStateManager.StateResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(AppStateManager.StateResult result) {
                AppStateManager.StateConflictResult conflictResult = result.getConflictResult();
                AppStateManager.StateLoadedResult loadedResult = result.getLoadedResult();
                if (loadedResult != null) {
                    processStateLoaded(loadedResult);

                } else if (conflictResult != null) {
                    processStateConflict(conflictResult);
                }
            }
        };
        private void processStateConflict(AppStateManager.StateConflictResult result) {
            // Need to resolve conflict between the two states.
            // We do that by taking the union of the two sets of cleared levels,
            // which means preserving the maximum star rating of each cleared
            // level:
            byte[] serverData = result.getServerData();
            byte[] localData = result.getLocalData();

            GameData localGame = new GameData(localData);
            GameData serverGame = new GameData(serverData);
            GameData resolvedGame = localGame.unionWith(serverGame);

            AppStateManager.resolve(getApiClient(), result.getStateKey(), result.getResolvedVersion(),
                    resolvedGame.toBytes()).setResultCallback(mResultCallback);
        }

        private void processStateLoaded(AppStateManager.StateLoadedResult result) {

            switch (result.getStatus().getStatusCode()) {
            case AppStateStatusCodes.STATUS_OK:
                // Data was successfully loaded from the cloud: merge with local data.
                gameData = gameData.unionWith(new GameData(result.getLocalData()));
                saveToCloud();
                gameData.saveDataLocal(settings);
                GameData tem = new GameData(result.getLocalData());
                System.out.println("Game Data: "+tem);
                System.out.println("Local Data: "+gameData);
                progress.cancel();
                break;
            case AppStateStatusCodes.STATUS_STATE_KEY_NOT_FOUND:
                // key not found means there is no saved data. To us, this is the same as
                // having empty data, so we treat this as a success.
                progress.cancel();
                break;
            case AppStateStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA:
                // can't reach cloud, and we have no local state. Warn user that
                // they may not see their existing progress, but any new progress won't be lost.
                progress.cancel();
                break;
            case AppStateStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_STALE_DATA:
                // can't reach cloud, but we have locally cached data.
                progress.cancel();
                break;
            case AppStateStatusCodes.STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED:
                // need to reconnect AppStateClient
                reconnectClient();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public GameData getGameData() {
            return this.gameData;
        }

        @Override
        public void saveDataToCloud() {
            saveToCloud();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnSinglePlayer:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.fragment_container, singlePlayerFragment ).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();

            break;
            case R.id.btnMultiplayer:
                Intent selectLevelActivity = new Intent(this, MultiPlayerPlayActivity.class);
                startActivity(selectLevelActivity);
                break;
            case R.id.btnSetting:
                selectLevelActivity = new Intent(this, SettingActivity.class);
                startActivity(selectLevelActivity);
                break;
            case R.id.btnLeaderBoard:
                if (isSignedIn()) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
                    edit.putInt(VERY_CURIOUS_UNLOCK, 1);
                    edit.commit();
                    unlockAchievement(R.string.achievement_very_curious,"Very Curious");
                    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(getApiClient()),RC_UNUSED);
                } else {
                    showAlert(getString(R.string.leaderboards_not_available));
                }


                break;
            case R.id.btnAchivement:
                if (isSignedIn()) {
                    unlockAchievement(R.string.achievement_curious, "Curious");
                    startActivityForResult(Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(getApiClient()),RC_UNUSED);
                }else {
                    showAlert(getString(R.string.achievements_not_available));
                }
            break;
            case R.id.btnHelp:
                QuizCompletedForMultiPlayerDialog cdd=new QuizCompletedForMultiPlayerDialog(this);

                cdd.show();
                break;
        }
            if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
                beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
                signOut();
                findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_out_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.sign_in_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

         @Override
          public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (adView != null) {
              adView.resume();
            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onPause() {
            if (adView != null) {
              adView.pause();
            }
            super.onPause();
          }

          /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
          @Override
          public void onDestroy() {
            // Destroy the AdView.
            if (adView != null) {
              adView.destroy();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
          }


          class QuizCompletedForMultiPlayerDialog extends Dialog implements
            android.view.View.OnClickListener {

        public Activity c;
        public Dialog d;
        int levelStaus = 1;

        int levelNo = 1;
        int lastLevelScore = 0;
        public QuizCompletedForMultiPlayerDialog(Activity a) {
            super(a);
            this.c = a;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.custom_help_dialog);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btnPlayAgain:

                break;
            case R.id.btnQuit:

            default:
                break;
            }
            dismiss();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Display Ads after some interval of game start.
     */
    private final Runnable mUpdateUITimerTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            displayInterstitial(true);

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: You've included a lot of code, but no specific question. Tell us what is wrong with **your attempt** to solve your problem.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames#loading_saved_games
here is a link from google explaining how to add saved games and cloud save api to your app but there is no explanation of how to migrate from appstate api to new saved games :( ! i'm just trying to do some reskin to this app

Comment: I take it you didn't scroll all the way down to the [migrating from the AppState API section](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames#migrating_from_the_appstate_api)?